# Laravel Sanctum SPA and Mobile App "CSRF token mismatch"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I need Laravel Sanctum to support both SPA and Mobile App (Bearer) authentication. The issue is that I can't get both to work in parallel.

The SPA works perfectly fine, but the mobile app throws a "CSRF token mismatch error" when calling any protected endpoints. The issue seems to be the **Origin** header.

I noticed that the production mobile app's Origin header is "http://localhost/". If in Postman I use that value as the Origin header, the endpoints throw the same CSRF token mismatch error.

[image]

If I change the Origin header to anything else, everything works perfectly.

[image]

These are the contents of my config/sanctum.php:

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
    '%s%s',
    'localhost,localhost:3000,localhost:8080,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
    env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
))),
```

"localhost" is already there so I am not sure why the Bearer token auth fails when the Origin = "http://localhost"

I tried setting my .env `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` to "http://localhost", and this makes the Mobile App work perfectly, but then it breaks the SPA.

Answer (score 6):

Turns out the **Origin** and **Referer** headers tell Laravel that it should use the cookie-based authentication system and ignore the Bearer token. The code that handles this is in vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/Http/Middleware/EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStatefull.php

To force Laravel to NOT use cookie-based authentication on my mobile app, I had to set my production .env `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` to the actual production domain of the SPA. It basically tells Laravel "you should only use cookie-based auth on this domain".

If you leave `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` unset, it will default to "localhost", which is the Origin domain of any Android app. Meaning, the Android app will attempt to use cookie auth, which is not what anybody wants.